# Change status in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make status for Discord bot like "Listening People's Problems". But how to change "Playing" into "Listening"?

Comment: For anyone else who was as confused as I was: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro . Or maybe I'm just out of touch?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snippets I saved while I was writing my bot a while ago

`.setActivity({type: "LISTENING", "WATCHING", "PLAYING", "ETC."})`

---

```
client.user.setPresence({
  game: {
    name: 'game',
    type: 0
   }
})
```

---

0: playing

1: streaming

2: listening

3: watching

---

They depreciate things quiet often, try something in the scope of `change_presence`

### Check this out for reference: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107424/discord.Game

Hope this inspires something

Comment: they depreciate things quiet often, try something in the scope of 'change_presence'
check this out for reference: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107424/discord.Game

Comment: @SÜLEYMANLI You're likely trying to `await` a coroutine outside of an `async def` function.  Could you share your code as text in an edit to your question?